# how to deploy ionic app to windows 10 device

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to deploy my ionic mobile application to a windows 10 device after adding the windows platform with

`ionic platform add "windows@https://aka.ms/cordova-win10"`

which was successful, I then decided to run it with

```
ionic run windows
```

that is when the error came up like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, some prerequisites (be 100% sure to have them all):

- Windows 10 SO
- [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
- Visual Studio 2015, with “Tools for Universal Windows App Development, Cross Platform Mobile Development > HTML/JavaScript”
  selected when choosing options.
- [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Then you should be able to run your app.

Check outo more info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/07/29/targeting-windows-10-with-your-apache-cordova-app/) and [here](http://blog.aveni.us/index.php/2015/12/19/creating-windows-10-universal-apps-ionic-framework/#sthash.nUpFfXkH.dpbs)

Comment: Hope that helps someone, it was usefull for me that time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this line to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

like this:

```
<platform name="windows">
    ...
</platform>
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

It needs to be outside the Platform specific parameters.